# Angular Split HTML files

Tags: angular

I know this subject has already been discussed but my issue is the following:

I have a component which contain many functions, this component should display different HTML depending on the parameter it receives. My issue is that my HTML file is too big and I want to split it in two files.

I don't want to make something like:

```
<div *ngIf="myParam1">
500 line
</div>
<div *ngIf="myParam2">
500 line
</div>
```

The `ng-include` directive of **angularJS** was perfect but now it seems like the only way is to create two components. But I don't want to do that because I will duplicate all the function of my main component in two component. (I can keep the main component and pass everything to the sub component but there is too many things to pass, it will be horrible to code that).

My question is, is there a workaround to avoid typescript duplication when two html templates are needed? because if there is no workaround it's sounds like crazy.. I don't know why they remove the `ng-include` :/

Comment: take a look at `ngTemplateOutlet` directive. It should do what you want. https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: But the best practice solution would definitely be the one with seperate components, where you either pull out the common logic in a service or in the parent component, like sam suggested

Answer (score 0):

Why not make 2x components and then make them presentational only. You can use Output() events from your child component when interaction occurs, calling a function on the parent - this way you keep your functional logic on the parent shared between the child components avoiding duplication of logic.

An example would be like this.

**Child**

**TS**

```
@Output() event = new EventEmitter<any>;
@Input() button_name: any;

emitEvent() {
    this.event.emit();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="emitEvent()">{{button_name}}</button>
```

**Parent**

**TS**

```
changeButtonName() {
    // could modify data here for example to update the child component.
    this.button_name = "Changed value of name";

}
```

**HTML**

```
<child-component *ngIf="myParam1" (event)="changeButtonName()" [button_name]="button_name"></child-component>

<child-component2 *ngIf="myParam2" (event)="changeButtonName()" [button_name]="button_name"></child-component>
```